# Why can I open a Bootstrap Dropdown in document ready but not in my own function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**Information and Question:**
If you run the JSFiddle you'll notice that the dropdown pops open like it's supposed to when the document loads but when you click the button it doesn't.  It's the same exact code but I can't for the life of me figure out why it doesn't have the same results.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pLsuxkaa/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="testfun();" value="Test"/>
<p></p>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="dropdown testmenu">
    <a id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
        Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li>Content 1</li>
        <li>Content 2</li>
        <li>Content 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Scripts:**

```
$(function () 
{
    $('p').html('started');
    $('.testmenu .dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');
});

function testfun() 
{
    $('p').html('test button pushed');
    $('.testmenu .dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When u write

```
 $('.testmenu .dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');
```

You declare a new dropdown, after this you just have to toggle like this :

```
$('.testmenu .dropdown-menu').toggle();
```

Complete code :

```
$(function () 
{
    $('p').html('started');
    $('.testmenu .dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');
});

function testfun() 
{
    $('p').html('test button pushed');
    $('.testmenu .dropdown-menu').toggle();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so looks like [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-methods) is incorrect?

Comment: @BryantMiano : apparently yes, `Options None` and you can give 'toggle' option, that's strange but that fix this problem, test it on fiddle

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, It works just fine.  That'll teach me to read the documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to call  `testfun()` from inside the `$(function ()` (document ready) function, as using bootstrap functions requires the page to be finished loading

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind an event to the input button, and have the callback function open the dropdown menu. Here's an example:

```
$('input').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('p').html('test button pushed');
    $('.testmenu .dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

And here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sx94au4o/).